# the imported project "c:\program > files\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\v10.0\windows azure > tools\1.6\microsoft.windowsAzure.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I have this error when i'm try to load my project in visual studio 2010. I already installed `Windows Azure SDK` and `Visual Studio Cloud Service` in my computer but still its not working.

> the imported project "c:\program
>   files\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\v10.0\windows azure
>   tools\1.6\microsoft.windowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that
>   the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file
>   exist on disk.

Any one can help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install the [Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/F/4/DF442AB0-FAAE-44FF-A04E-F41E72FE6B6F/WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe). Note that you're still using the 1.6. Version 1.7 is the latest version today, so if you're starting a new project you might want to look at that version in order to access the [new Windows Azure features](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/whats-new-for-the-windows-azure-developer-lots-2/).